# make div scrollable inside fixed sidebar (css)

Tags: html, css, scrollable

can sombody help me ? 
The div (the last one) inside the sidebar sould be scrollable.
I wanna use the sidebar for some functions like phonenumber search and displaying birthdays.

In the last div I wanna show a lot of notifications. 
min-height of each notification is about 100px. 
If there are too many i wanna make the div scrollable.

Thats my code sofar:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/177pysae/)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 4px solid blue;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 36px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 4px solid yellow;
}

.sidebar_item {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.item_header {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 36px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 4px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">Navbar</div>
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar_item">
    <div class="item_header">Header</div>
    Content
  </div>

  <div class="sidebar_item">
    <div class="item_header">Header</div>
    Content
  </div>

  <div class="sidebar_item">
    <div class="item_header">Header</div>
    Content
  </div>


  <div class="sidebar_item">
    <div class="item_header">Header</div>
    Content
  </div>

  <div class="sidebar_item">
    <div class="item_header">Header</div>
    Content
  </div>

  <!-- Scrollable div -->
  <div class="sidebar_item">
    <div class="item_header">Header</div>
    <p>TOP</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>BOTTOM</p>
  </div>


</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>TOP</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>BOTTOM</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does adding `overflow:auto` on `.sidebar` have the effect you want?

Comment: @Jonathan Unfortunately not. I just want the last div to be scrollable not the whole sidebar.

Comment: What if the screen is so small that the 2 last divs are not visible?

Comment: @Jonathan well never thought about that. But that sidebar only should be visible on desktops not on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

The scrollable div change to another name i changed it to 
    sidebar_item2

and applied the following css

```
.sidebar_item2 {
    overflow-x:auto;
    height:100px;
}
```

Hope that is what you are trying.

Comment: not quite. I want the div to stretch the available height. If height is set to 100px there will only be one notification visible.

Comment: you do not have to specify a height then just say height auto. I am guessing you want top to stay on top and bottom to stay bottom and where it says content the functions will go there?

Comment: top and bottom is only there to see if the div is scrollable. all inside the item should be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include the `overflow:auto;` style in the sidebar class.

Comment: please see the comments under my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last child to be different than the others ... scroll on y say. There is a Pseudo-class selector for that.

```
 .sidebar:last-child { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Comment: can you show me on my fiddle ?  It seems a good answer but I cannot make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Used `.sidebar_item:last-child` Pseudo-class selector for that and calculate the height using `calc()`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 4px solid blue;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 36px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 4px solid yellow;
}

.sidebar_item {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.item_header {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 36px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 4px solid purple;
}
.sidebar_item:last-child {
  overflow-y:auto;
  height: calc( 100% - 215px);
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">Navbar</div>
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar_item">
    <div class="item_header">Header</div>
    Content
  </div>

  <div class="sidebar_item">
    <div class="item_header">Header</div>
    Content
  </div>

  <div class="sidebar_item">
    <div class="item_header">Header</div>
    Content
  </div>


  <div class="sidebar_item">
    <div class="item_header">Header</div>
    Content
  </div>

  <div class="sidebar_item">
    <div class="item_header">Header</div>
    Content
  </div>

  <!-- Scrollable div -->
  <div class="sidebar_item">
    <div class="item_header">Header</div>
    <p>TOP</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>BOTTOM</p>
  </div>


</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>TOP</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>bla</p>
  <p>BOTTOM</p>
</div>
```

Working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nyuvLgpw/)

Comment: working fine. I guess 215px is sum of the other items ? What if there are more or less ? Is there a way to calculate this ?

Comment: yes 215px is sum of other items. if there are more or less  you need to calculate height according to that. you can used jquery for that.